# Positional Encoding for time series based data for Transformer DNN models

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

In several academic papers, researchers use the following positional encoding to denote the positioning of elements in a sequence, whether it be a time series-based sequence or words in a sentence for NLP purposes.

My question is how the positioning is actually applied to the data before it is fed to the deep neural network (in my case a transformer network):

- Are the positional values added directly to the actual values of the elements in the sequence (or to the word representation values)? Or are they concatinated? Is the positional embedding part of the data preprocessing stage?
- Does the Tensorflow/Keras `MultiHeadAttention` layer actually already contain an `Embeeding` layer that takes care of the positional encoding? Or not?
- What about the normalization of data? Are only the actual element values normalized and then the positional encoding is added to that normalized value? Or is the positional encoding value added to the raw value of the element and the resulting values are normalized?

I am interested in actual implementation details not the conceptual part of positional encoding as I read most of the academic papers on positional encoding already. Unfortunately, most academic papers fall short of describing in detail at what stage and how precisely the positional encoding is applied to the data structure.

Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: Regarding your first and third questions. The positional embedding is a vector of same dimension as your input embedding, that is ```added``` onto each of your "word embeddings" to encode the positional information of words in a sentence (since it's no longer sequential). You could view it as a preprocessing step to incorporate positional information into your word vector representations. The normalization step is applied to the word embeddings themselves (normalized to vectors of unit length) before adding the positional encoding.

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi, thank you for your comment. When you say "vector of same dimension as your input embedding", I understand the concept of embeddings for words in NLP. But what about time series-based data? Would the embedding vector be all the features at the same position in the sequence? My time series based input data is of the following shape: (batch, sequence, features). So, for each position in a given sequence I have n features. Would the positional encoding be applied to each value of each feature at any given position in the sequence?

Comment: In the case of time series-based data, your input embedding would be a ```d_model``` dimensional vector generated by mapping the input time series data to a
vector of dimension ```d_model``` through a fully-connected network. Then you treat these input embeddings like usual; where you generate positional encodings (of same dimension as ```d_model```) using sine and cosine functions for each position depending on where it occurred in the sequence. Then apply element-wise addition of the
input vector with the positional encoding vector.

Comment: But would this not take away a lot of the benefits of the parallelization capabilities of the transformer network? Naively, I feel it to be much more beneficial to attach the positional encoding in the data preprocessing stage rather then performing element-wise additions inside the network. The attention heads would still operate in parallel, however, a lot of the overhead would be moved to the data preprocessing stage and the dataset with all encordings could be stored and loaded very efficiently via data pipelines....

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi, Omar, I implemented positional encoding just as prescribed in the "Attention is all you need" paper. However, adding the positional encodings make the model perform much worse. It takes around 2-3 epochs for the model to reach an accuracy level of 99% for "toy [easily predictable datasets]", whereas adding positional encodings takes over 100 epochs to reach the same accuracy level. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positional encoding is just a way to let the model differentiates two elements (words) that're the same but which appear in different positions in a sequence.

After applying embeddings in a LM - language model for example, we add PE to add an information about position of each word.

> Are the positional values added directly to the actual values of the elements in the sequence (or to the word representation values)? Or are they concatinated? Is the positional embedding part of the data preprocessing stage?

Yes PE values are just **added** directly to actual values (embeddings in a LM). This will results that the embedding vector of the word `a` that appears in the beginning of the sequence will be different of the embedding vector of the same word that appears in the middle of the sequence. And no, PE is not a part of data preprocessing stage.

Here's an example of code:

```py
class PositionalEncodingLayer(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, d_model, max_len=100):
        super(PositionalEncodingLayer, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.max_len = max_len
    
    def get_angles(self, positions, indexes):
        d_model_tensor = torch.FloatTensor([[self.d_model]]).to(positions.device)
        angle_rates = torch.pow(10000, (2 * (indexes // 2)) / d_model_tensor)
        return positions / angle_rates

    def forward(self, input_sequences):
        """
        :param Tensor[batch_size, seq_len] input_sequences
        :return Tensor[batch_size, seq_len, d_model] position_encoding
        """
        positions = torch.arange(input_sequences.size(1)).unsqueeze(1).to(input_sequences.device) # [seq_len, 1]
        indexes = torch.arange(self.d_model).unsqueeze(0).to(input_sequences.device) # [1, d_model]
        angles = self.get_angles(positions, indexes) # [seq_len, d_model]
        angles[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(angles[:, 0::2]) # apply sin to even indices in the tensor; 2i
        angles[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(angles[:, 1::2]) # apply cos to odd indices in the tensor; 2i
        position_encoding = angles.unsqueeze(0).repeat(input_sequences.size(0), 1, 1) # [batch_size, seq_len, d_model]
        return position_encoding

class InputEmbeddingAndPositionalEncodingLayer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, max_len, d_model, dropout):
        super(InputEmbeddingAndPositionalEncodingLayer, self).__init__()
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        self.token_embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.position_encoding = PositionalEncodingLayer(d_model=d_model, max_len=max_len)

    def forward(self, sequences):
        """
        :param Tensor[batch_size, seq_len] sequences
        :return Tensor[batch_size, seq_len, d_model]
        """
        token_embedded = self.token_embedding(sequences) # [batch_size, seq_len, d_model]
        position_encoded = self.position_encoding(sequences) # [batch_size, seq_len, d_model]
        return self.dropout(token_embedded) + position_encoded # [batch_size, seq_len, d_model]
```

> Does the Tensorflow/Keras MultiHeadAttention layer actually already contain an Embeeding layer that takes care of the positional encoding? Or not?

Simply No. You have to build PE yourself.

> What about the normalization of data? Are only the actual element values normalized and then the positional encoding is added to that normalized value? Or is the positional encoding value added to the raw value of the element and the resulting values are normalized?

The normalization part is at your discretion. You do what you want. But you should apply the normalization. Also, PE is added to normalized values not actual one.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I would add that PE is not just in order to differentiate between two otherwise equal words at different positions in a sentence but also to embed awareness of general positioning of different words because order of words do sometimes matter a lot, semantically. But here I deal with time series-based data and the order of elements in the sequence absolutely matters. Otherwise I found your comments very helpful and value adding. Thank you

Comment: What I am still confused about is why we can't add the positional encoding at the data pre-processing stage. Why does it matter?